# Redirect doesn't work correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a small htaccess file, which contains some simple rules.
First I want to redirect or to add **www** at the begin of the main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|serv)\.(.*\-.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In the second step I want to remove the folder **serv** from the URI.
I have following folder structure:

www.maindomain.com

- serv/
- content of the main web page

To do that I have following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^serv.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/serv.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /serv/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works so far, but my own rewrite rules conflicts with the conditions and rules above:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/$ search.php [L,QSA]
```

So my URI get sometimes something like that *www.maindomain.de/search/search*.

Here is my full htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|serv)\.(.*\-.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^serv.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/serv.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /serv/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/$ search.php [L,QSA]
```

What is wrong? I don't find the mistake.

Furthermore I want to know if it is possible, if the subdomain isn't **serv** and the URI doesn't contain **serv** that the subdomain will be redirected to **www**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if it is possible, if the subdomain isn't serv and the URI doesn't contain serv that the subdomain will be redirected to www

For the last part of your question, add the following to your .htaccess file

```
#if the subdomain is not serv
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^serv\.[^\.]+\.de$ [NC]
#and the uri does not contain serv
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*serv.*$ [NC]
#redirect to www
RewriteRule .* http://www.maindomain.de%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301]
```

**Edit:**
I replaced %1 reference with the host Above, which you can change to match your actual host.

For the first part of your question, your rule below will match any host that does not begin with www. or serv. that does not have a dash in the domain i.e. it will match `www.maindomain.com` because it does not have a '-`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|serv)\.(.*\-.*)\.com [NC]
```

This will result in an infinite redirect as you observed.

To **fix** it change it to the following

```
#if host is NOT www.anything.com or serv.anything.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|serv)\.[^\.]+\.com$ [NC]
#redirect to www.maindomain.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your RewriteRule seems not to work. The reference %1 won't be resolved. If I call the maindomain directly, I got an error, that there are too many redirects.

Comment: Tried again and www. result into infinite loop. Redirect from http://wiki.../notTheWikiFolder works.

Comment: Sorry - I had a typo and forgot to escape the period `[^\.]` - which is fixed above